# Replacing </div> with a word in a file

Tags: bash

I would like to change `</div>` in a very long document almost, consists of almost 2500 pages, with the word "Index:", but it never worked. I tried `sed`in many different ways for example:

```
 sed '/s^[</div>]/Index:/g'
```

But it didn't work!

would you please let me know what is the correct command?

example

```
</div>
</div>
<script src="https://cdn.pkgs.org/assets/js/main.min.js?v10"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () </div> {
app.init("pkgs.org", 101);
})
</div>
</script>
</body>
```

i want it

```
Index:
Index:
<script src="https://cdn.pkgs.org/assets/js/main.min.js?v10"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function () Index {
app.init("pkgs.org", 101);
})
Index:
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: Please provide sample input and output, and the `sed` examples you tried. Note that, ingeneral, [parsing HTML is not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags)

Comment: it is not html, we clean this document frome very extra charcters we only has </div> and cant moe it out the book

Comment: Downvoters, what is wrong with this question? It is very clear in what it wants to achieve, and what the OP has done to try and solve the problem. If you believe there to be some issue, please tell the OP in the comments. That's what they're for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you remove the square brackets, use `%` instead of `/` as a `sed` delimiter to stop confusion with the `/` in `</div>`, move the delimiter before the s to after it, and remove the caret, the regex works:

```
sed 's%</div>%Index:%g'
```

Comment: Easier to read: Take other delimiters. Percent signs are also quite visible. This way, you need not escape the slash.

Answer (score 5):

I see three problems:

1. The syntax of your sed command is wrong. I believe what you meant was the search and replace command, so the 's' must come before the slash:

   `sed 's/^[</div>]/Index:/g'`
2. The fact that your string has the slash ('/') character in your search string messes up with sed. So you could either escape the slash with a backslash:

   `sed 's/^[<\/div>]/Index:/g'`

   or use another character as separator:

   `sed 's|^[</div>]|Index:|g'`
3. You are using square brackets (`[</div>]`) in your search, which is not what you want. This expression matches any of the characters inside the square brackets once. Try the following command without square brackets:

   `sed 's|^</div>|Index:|g'`

Comment: Could the anonymous downvoters please leave some feedback?

Comment: Yeah, this is really disappointing, taking the time to answer a question and getting downvoted without an explanation.

Comment: It appears that the whole question, and answers too, have been downvoted.

Comment: @Cyclic3, I cannot comment on your answer and the edit is less than 6 characters, maybe you could remove the quoting on the slash of /div since it is no longer necessary.